# JavaFX - Virtual Keyboard Doesn't Show When the App Jar is Generated

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx, virtual-keyboard

I have created a **JavaFX** application in **IntelliJ14.14** that will use the  **JavaFX Virtual Keyboard**. I have add the following properties in the mainApp class controller:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.setProperty("com.sun.javafx.isEmbedded", "true");
    System.setProperty("com.sun.javafx.touch", "true");
    System.setProperty("com.sun.javafx.virtualKeyboard", "javafx");
    launch(args);
}
```

When I run the app from IntelliJ everything works fine. The virtual keyboard works perfectly.

But when I generate the **Jar** file of the application from *Build -> Build Artifacts... -> Build* and execute it, the keyboard never shows because the VM options are not being set.

It's something I'm missing...?

Thanks in advance...

**EDIT**

I have found a way to make this work, running the file from the **cmd** with this command:

```
java -Dcom.sun.javafx.isEmbedded=true -Dcom.sun.javafx.virtualKeyboard="javafx" -Dcom.sun.javafx.touch=true -jar myApp.jar
```

However I want to make this just executing the Jar file...

**EDIT**

There is another nearby way to accomplish what I want...

Create a file **.bat** in the same folder of the jar and put in it:

```
start javaw -Dcom.sun.javafx.isEmbedded=true -Dcom.sun.javafx.virtualKeyboard="javafx" -Dcom.sun.javafx.touch=true -jar myApp.jar
```

So when tha **.bat** file is executed and the jar file is started, the system properties are loaded correctly...

Comment: Try moving the `System.setProperty(...)` calls to the `Application.init()` method.

Comment: Not working, same result...

Comment: Rather than requiring your users to run a .bat file (which wouldn't work cross-platform), you could create a solution in Java that re-executes your program with the appropriate command line arguments.

Comment: @Vulcan  a example for doing that...?

Comment: @geme23 The [`ProcessBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) class provides necessary tools to set up a process to run your application.

Comment: This is the ONLY option you have: http://blog.codejava.net/nam/trick-for-passing-vm-options-when-launching-jar-file/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class MyApp {  
    public static void main(String[] args) {  

        if (args.length == 0) {  
            try {  
                // re-launch the app itselft with VM option passed  
                Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] {"java", "-Dcom.sun.javafx.isEmbedded=true", "-Dcom.sun.javafx.virtualKeyboard=\"javafx\"", "-Dcom.sun.javafx.touch=true", "-jar", "myApp.jar"});  
            } catch (IOException ioe) {  
                ioe.printStackTrace();  
            }  
            System.exit(0);  
        }  

        // Run the main program with the VM option set  
        //...  
        //...  
    }  
}
```